# Deploy angular app on apache server

Tags: angular, production-environment

To deploy my angular app on server, I run the following command: `ng build --prod`. But in the dist folder that I get, I don't have the `index.html` file. I wonder if it is a best practice to copy and paste the `index.html` file that I have or if there is something else that i am missing.

`angular-cli.json`

```js
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "main"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../../target/frontend",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The build was OK or did it fail?

Comment: The build is ok. No error is shown in the console

Comment: @edkeveked `ng build --prod` should have `index.html`. check your `angular-cli.json` and under `app` there shoul be `index` key

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya what should I check in the angular-cli.json file?

Comment: @edkeveked post your `angular-cli.json` here

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @edkeveked your code is being generated in `target/frontend` this folder and not in dist folder

Comment: Could you post it as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: @edkeveked Did it work?

Comment: Yes, Now I can see the generated index.html file. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149375/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-edkeveked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line
`"outDir": "../../target/frontend",` 
suggests that your code is being generated in `target\frontend` folder and not in `dist` folder. If you want to change it to `dist`. change that line to 
`"outDir": "dist",` from `"outDir": "../../target/frontend",`